# Greek characters affecting line spacing in emacs

Tags: emacs, unicode, fonts

When I have Greek characters in emacs the line spacing before the next line is increased, which is pretty annoying and weird. Strangely any other unicode characters seem to be fine.

What is going on here and how can I make the line spacing consistent with other characters?

[image: strange line spacings with greek characters]

The version of emacs is:
GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.12) of 2012-09-22 on batsu, modified by Debian

on linux mint (and using xmonad as a window manager but I doubt that has anything to do with it).

The example above is using "emacs -q" launched from a urxvt terminal with no .Xdefaults file (I then enabled linum-mode so that the line spacings are more visible).

Edit: The same thing happens if using the "-Q" options (I only just found out the difference between -q and -Q).

Comment: Does it happen in GUI emacs?

Comment: Sorry it is running in a GUI (GTK+), urxvt was just used to launch it. I thought that might be relevant because shell variables sometimes seem to affect emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the Greek letters are from a completely different font. In addition to stylistic difference, this may cause different line height. So check out whether you can change the font to one that contains all the characters needed.

Comment: This was the problem. It turns out that I had used maths Greek characters instead of normal Greek. I guess the fonts I tried don't support the maths Greek letters.